# Green Tea After Dinner

Tags: time-of-day, meal, tea, drinks, liquids

Where Im from (West Pakistan), there is an old tradition of serving Green Tea after dinner, which is meant to burn the oil & help with digestion.

From what I have read, we should drink liquids before the meal, not after.

Is there is scientific proof that green tea has any benefits, when taken after a meal? Shouldn't we be drinking it before rather than after?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is off topic since our scope change, but is being preserved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Green tea has thermogenic properties and promotes fat oxidation  beyond that explained by its caffeine content per se. If green tea extract are drunk **during** the meal there is a proved effect of it on fat oxidation.

[Efficacy of a green tea extract](http://ajcn.nutrition.org/content/70/6/1040.short)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. BTW, the link doesnt open correctly (Firefox latest here)

Comment: The link works for me but as an option here is an another link to the article http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10584049

Comment: @bantandor it works now because I edited it :)